# Run task before compilation using Android Gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-build

I have a very simple `build.gradle` file with the following content:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"
    compileSdkVersion 17

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}

task generateSources {
    doFirst {
        def script = "python GenerateSources.py".execute()
        script.in.eachLine {line -> println line}
        script.err.eachLine {line -> println "ERROR: " + line}
        script.waitFor()
    }
}
```

What I want is to run `generateSources` task before java compilation is started. I found several solutions how to do that, like `compileJava.dependsOn("generateSources")`, but unfortunately they give an error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Android'.
> Could not find property 'compileJava' on root project 'Android'.
```

I don't know Gradle and can't understand what's wrong with this code. So I would like to know how I can fix this error.

Comment: I thinks in this thread you will find solution 
[assembleRelease task dependency - Ask for keystore password][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144878/assemblerelease-task-dependency-ask-for-keystore-password

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The proper way to run a task before Java compilation on Android is to make a compilation task for each variant depend on your task.

```
afterEvaluate {
  android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.javaCompiler.dependsOn(generateSources)
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling your custom task here?

Comment: `generateSources` is the custom task. And `javaCompiler` tasks becomes dependent on `generateSources`.

Comment: I get an error: **Could not find property 'android' on root project**

Comment: You have to apply the Android plugin before this code.

Comment: @Michael how do you do that? I'm using Android Studio

Comment: You just have to put this code into your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @Michael How do I do this for multiple tasks?

Comment: You can call `variant.javaCompiler.dependsOn(taskName)` for every task. Another approach is to have a chain of task and call `variant.javaCompiler.dependsOn(taskName)` for the root one.

Comment: `variant.javaCompiler` is now obsolete, you should use `variant.javaCompileProvider.get()`

Answer (score 30):

Apparently, the `android` plugin doesn't add a `compileJava` task (like the `java` plugin would). You can check which tasks are available with `gradle tasks --all`, and pick the right one for your (otherwise correct) dependency declaration.

EDIT:

Apparently, the `android` plugin defers creation of tasks in such a way that they can't be accessed eagerly as usual. One way to overcome this problem is to defer access until the end of the *configuration phase*:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    compileJava.dependsOn(generateSources)
}
```

Chances are that there is a more idiomatic way to solve your use case, but quickly browsing the [Android plugin docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) I couldn't find one.

Comment: What is it that doesn't work, and what's the exact error message?

Comment: The problem is the same as before: `Could not find property 'compileDebug' on root project 'Android'.`

Comment: And you verified that `compileDebug` exists? Does `gradle compileDebug` work? Did you add the dependency declaration at the bottom of the build script? You can also try `tasks.compileDebug`, but it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: `gradle compileDebug` works fine. At the bottom of the file I added `compileDebug.dependsOn("generateSources")`. When I write `tasks.compileDebug` instead of `compileDebug` gradle gives me an error `Could not find property 'compileDebug' on task set.`

Comment: Browsing the Android plugin docs, I realized that it works quite differently from most other plugins. Does `gradle.projectsEvaluated { tasks.compileDebug.dependsOn(generateSources) }` work? Probably there's a more idiomatic way though.

Comment: Yeah, seems it works! Could you please add it to the answer and explain what it means?

Comment: Awesome - have been at this for days now not understanding why the usual dependsOn failed for the pre defined tasks. Now I can finally add a dependency to the connectedCheck.

Comment: Hello Peter Niederwieser, it giving me below error. Could not find property 'compileJava' on com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated@44b35022.

Comment: The task name seems to have changed to [`compileDebugJava`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/BasePlugin.groovy#1076).

Comment: I've got a task that needs to run before the Android build. Task copies a jar file into the libs directory. Somehow, this happends too late for the Android build. My android build always fails the first time after a clean. Then the second time it works ( since the jar file is there then). How do run the task that copies the jar file soon enough?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser any chance you can update your answer? It's seems to be quite out of date. (Sorry if this sounds a bit rude, it's not meant that way)

Comment: Why is it out of date?

Comment: Well, your answer still says "compileJava.dependsOn(...)" which doesnt work, as discussed in comments.

Comment: `./gradlew tasks --all` in the project directory also shows the task's description.

Answer (score 15):

You can see task execution in terminal running task for example `gradle assemble`. Try this one, it is started practically before anything.

```
android {
    ...
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
         preBuild.dependsOn(generateSources)
    }
    ...
}
```

**Edit**, this may not work in Android Studio, as the Android Gradle DSL does not have a `projectsEvaluated` method.

Comment: What?  I get an error: **Could not find property 'preBuild' on root project**

Comment: So, probably it doesn't exists now on newer versions of Gradle

Comment: Did it ever exist in Android Studio?  Or were you generally speaking about Gradle...

Comment: It was used in one of my projects Igor

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky just put prebuild.dependsOn('someTask') within the android { } block, works like a charm.  No need to invoke projectsEvaluated.

Comment: tsk...tsk..spent hours struggling with getting a task to run because I was putting related code ouside of the android {} block

Comment: @lasec0203 thanks for pointing this out. I have made an appropriate edit,

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"
    compileSdkVersion 17

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}

task generateSources {
    def script = "python GenerateSources.py".execute()
    script.in.eachLine {line -> println line}
    script.err.eachLine {line -> println "ERROR: " + line}
    script.waitFor()
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    preBuild.dependsOn generateSources
}

clean.dependsOn generateSources
clean.mustRunAfter generateSources
```

The last two lines are optional - they will invoke the "generateSources" task when executing a gradle clean

Comment: I get an error: **Could not find property 'preBuild' on project ':app'**

Comment: Any suggestion who can get build type related info in Gradle task  'generateSources'

Answer (score 0):

For those having a multi-project build and needing to run a task for each project before they're built (but it should also be ok if you have only the app project), you can write the task in the root build configuration script inside the `allprojects` closure and executing the task right there.

In root project `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
    task mytask {
        doFirst {
            println project.projectDir.name
        }
    }
    mytask.execute()
}
```

It will be executed for every build variant as well.

Gradle 4.1

Comment: This is bad since it will run for every invocation.  Including things like clean which probably isn't what you want.  Depending on what it does it could trigger uptodate checks to do more things.