# assembleRelease task dependency - Ask for keystore password

Tags: android, gradle

To avoid writing the keystore password in plain text, I'm trying to add a dependency to the *assembleRelease* task created by the android Gradle plugin.

I've checked the Gradle documentation [Manipulating existing tasks](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#N102B0) but I'm unable to place the dependency where it should

This is my task, defined in *$root$/myApp/build.gradle* above the android plugin.

```
task readPasswordFromInput << {
    def console = System.console()

    ext.keystorePassword = console.readLine('\n\n\n> Enter keystore password: ')
}

apply plugin: 'android'
```

Then, I've tried the two possibilities offered by Gradle: *task.dependsOn* and *task.doFirst*, but none works. The latter appears to be ignored, while *dependsOn* does add the dependency, but too late in the dependency chain. Running *./gradlew tasks --all* prints this

```
:assembleRelease - Assembles all Release builds [libs:ActionBarSherlock:bundleRelease, libs:DataDroid:bundleRelease, libs:SlidingMenu:bundleRelease]
    :compileRelease
    ...
    [SEVERAL TASKS]
    ...
    :packageRelease
    ...
    [SEVERAL TASKS]
    ...
    :readPasswordFromInput
```

The problem is, the keystore password is needed in the task *packageRelease*

Just as a side note, this works as I want

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            def console = System.console()

            ext.keystorePassword = console.readLine('\n\n\n> IF building release apk, enter keystore password: ')

            debuggable false

            signingConfigs.release.storePassword = ext.keystorePassword
            signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = ext.keystorePassword

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

but it asks for the password every single time you use *gradlew*, no matter if it's a *clean* or an *assemble*

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Intae Kim, here's my build.gradle version 2.0

```
task readPasswordFromInput << {
    def console = System.console()

    ext.keystorePassword = console.readLine('\n\n\n> Enter keystore password: ')

    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = ext.keystorePassword
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = ext.keystorePassword
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'validateReleaseSigning') {
        task.dependsOn readPasswordFromInput
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
```

Then, the buildTypes

```
release {
    debuggable false

    signingConfig signingConfigs.release

    runProguard true
    proguardFile 'my-file.txt'
}
```

Gradle executes correctly, but it only generates a release-unsigned.apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google recently added an official way to do this, see https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#secure-shared-keystore

It may not answer my original question (*ask for password*), but I think it's the better way to simplify the deploy and keep the credentials safe.

Answer (score 11):

try:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'packageRelease') {
        task.dependsOn readPasswordFromInput
    }
}
```

with your `readPasswordFromInput` task.

**UPDATED:**

In this way you can see that following code works.

```
def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames
if ('assemble' in runTasks || 'assembleRelease' in runTasks || 'a' in runTasks || 'aR' in runTasks) {
    android.signingConfigs.releaseSign.storeFile = file('/path/to/keystore')
    android.signingConfigs.releaseSign.storePassword = System.console().readLine('KeyStore Password: ')
    android.signingConfigs.releaseSign.keyAlias = ...
    android.signingConfigs.releaseSign.keyPassword = System.console().readLine('Alias Password: ')
    android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = android.signingConfigs.releaseSign
}
```

and if you encounter build fail, it may be required to asign an empty keysign config on `android.signingConfig`:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        releaseSign
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I had lost all hope on this ^^. I'm going to answer with my final code, for now I'm leaving yours as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks Intae, I'm able to read the password but gradle seems to read it on the first pass and does not generate the signed apk

Comment: [This github gist link](https://gist.github.com/jpeddicord/5710705) may help you.

Comment: that did the trick :) Please update your answer so that I can accept it. The original gist didn't work straight away, I had to do some minor modifications: https://gist.github.com/Maragues/5974337

Comment: Updated with another method. I'm using external script to keysign at this time, but it may be better with build.gradle only.

Comment: Since Android supports camel case shortcut see: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide, I would recommend to add  "'a' in runTasks || 'aR' in runTasks"  to check ...

Answer (score 6):

This is my complete solution for release key signing.

1. It detects if console is not available in daemon mode.
2. It hides passwords.

Use `gradle --no-daemon assembleRelease` if you are using daemon mode.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'validateReleaseSigning')
        task.dependsOn keystoreInfo
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '18.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            release {
                storeFile file('release.keystore')
                storePassword ''
                keyAlias ''
                keyPassword ''
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                debuggable false
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    }
}

task keystoreInfo << {
    def console = System.console()
    if (console == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException('no console available, use --no-daemon flag')

    def storeFile = console.readLine('Keystore: ')
    def storePassword = console.readPassword('Keystore password: ')
    def keyAlias = console.readLine('Key alias: ')
    def keyPassword = console.readPassword('Key password: ')

    android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(storeFile)
    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = new String(storePassword)
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = keyAlias
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = new String(keyPassword)
}
```

---

**Gist http://gist.github.com/grzegorz-zur/6416924**

Answer (score 3):

I've created solution, which works fine for me, you can test it out

```
android { 
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile = file('android.keystore')
            keyAlias = "my_key_alias"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

task readPasswordFromInput << {
    if(!project.hasProperty('keyStore') || !project.hasProperty('keyPass') || !project.hasProperty('storePass')) {
        println "\n\$ Enter signing details manually or run with \"-PkeyStore={key.store.name} -PstorePass={StoreSecretPassword} -PkeyPass={KeySecretPassword}\""   
    }

    if(!project.hasProperty('keyStore')) {
        def newKeyStore = System.console().readLine("\n\$ Enter keystore location or enter (default: android.keystore): ")
        if(newKeyStore != '') android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file('${newKeyStore}')
    } else {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(project.keyStore)
    }

    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = project.hasProperty('storePass') ? project.storePass : new String(System.console().readPassword("\$ Store password: "))
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = project.hasProperty('keyPass') ? project.keyPass : new String(System.console().readPassword("\$ Key password: "))
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'validateReleaseSigning') {
        task.dependsOn readPasswordFromInput
    }
}
```

Then you can pass all arguments from CLI on prompt (uses `readPassword`, so it won't be visible) or you can pass them as CLI arguments to script

```
gradle assemble
gradle assemble -PkeyStore="~/.android/my.keystore"
gradle assemble -PkeyStore="~/.android/my.keystore" -PstorePass="MyStorePass"
gradle assemble -PkeyStore="~/.android/my.keystore" -PstorePass="MyStorePass" -PkeyPass="MyKeyPass"
```

Comment: the script is nice, but I think it's better to avoid using passwords as command arguments in the shell - they could be available in the shell history later.

Comment: @snowdragon I think that too, that's why the script allows you to input them within prompts, having them in shell or command alias is just bonus

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do.

```
task('readPasswordFromInput') << {
    def console = System.console()

    ext.keystorePassword = console.readLine('\n\n\n> Enter keystore password: ')

    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = ext.keystorePassword
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = ext.keystorePassword
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name.matches("validateReleaseSigning")) {
        task.dependsOn('readPasswordFromInput')
    }
}


signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file("my-debug-key.keystore")
    }

    release {
        storeFile file("my-release-key.keystore")
        storePassword ""
        keyAlias "release_key"
        keyPassword ""
    }
}
```