# External dependencies on Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, makefile

I'm familiar with building large applications using `make`, but now I have begun using Android Studio and I want to understand how to do things I already do in a `Makefile`.

Here are a example that might help you frame an answer:

**Makefile example:** (minimalist)

```
INK=inkscape
INKFLAGS=--export-area-page

# Resolve *.png dependencies
drawable-mdpi/%.png: %.svg
         $(INK) $< --export-png=$@ -w 48 -h 48 $(INKFLAGS) 

drawable-hdpi/%.png: %.svg
         $(INK) $< --export-png=$@ -w 72 -h 72 $(INKFLAGS) 

drawable-xdpi/%.png: %.svg
         $(INK) $< --export-png=$@ -w 96 -h 96 $(INKFLAGS)
```

**More simple example:**

```
drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png: ic_launcher.svg
         inkscape ic_launcher.svg --export-png=ic_launcher.png -w 48 -h 48 --export-area-page 

drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png: ic_launcher.svg
         inkscape ic_launcher.svg --export-png=ic_launcher.png -w 72 -h 72 --export-area-page
```

***How to do that in Gradle?***

*I want to resolve external dependencies such as mentioned in the above example. Actually I'm doing it via 'make', but i want to completely remove this extra step.*

Comment: Gradle by default compiles all drawable media from the "drawable" folder in your android project. It also recognises subfolders such as drawable-hdpi and drawable-mdpi automatically and will use those if appropriate and available to look up appropriate images for a resolution. There is a `dependencies` tag in the build.gradle file but from what I know it's mainly used to add externals JARS from the project or like Maven, to supply an address to an external repository to download a library for you. Hope it helps you on your way a bit.

Comment: @G_V i know that, i want to resolve external dependencies such as mentioned in my example. Is unproductive exporting each image manually when is modified. In fact currently i'm doing it using 'make', but i want to completely remove this extra step.

Comment: I can imagine, I prescale everything down in code on a background thread myself, then cache what I need for as long as I need it. Works well enough unless you have hundreds of large drawables, in which case the scaling itself still won't slow down the app much but the garbage collector does. I can't really help you but perhaps Gradle's [recommended books](https://www.gradle.org/books) are of more use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to run external commands from Grandle and integrate those into your build process. My example runs `inkscape.exe` on Windows and defines its parameters in the build script, you can also just run a shell script this way.

The following code goes into the `app\build.gradle` file. Task `convertDrawable` is written in Groovy syntax and accomplishes the following (*tl;dr it is an implementation of your "simple example"*):

- It looks through all the `*.svg` files in a custom folder `art/drawable`
- Within each of those `*.svg` files, looks through all the `drawable-*` folders in your resources folder
- Based on `drawable-*` folder name, determine the target resolution.
- Then calls `inkscape.exe` to convert each `*.svg` to `*.png` with the required size.

Code:

```
task convertDrawables() {
    def ink =  'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Inkscape\\inkscape.exe'

    // look for *.svg files in app/src/art/drawable folder
    new File('app\\src\\art\\drawable').eachFileMatch(~/.*\.svg/) { file ->
        // look for destination folders
        new File('app\\src\\main\\res').eachFileMatch(~/drawable-.*/) { outputDir ->

            // define size based on folder name
            def size = ''
            switch (outputDir.getAbsolutePath()) {
                case ~/.*-ldpi/:
                    size = '36'
                    break
                case ~/.*-mdpi/:
                    size = '48'
                    break
                case ~/.*-hdpi/:
                    size = '72'
                    break
                case ~/.*-xhdpi/:
                    size = '96'
                    break
                case ~/.*-xxhdpi/:
                    size = '144'
                    break
                case ~/.*-xxxhdpi/:
                    size = '192'
                    break
            }
            def cmd = ink + ' ' + file.getCanonicalPath() + ' --export-png=' + outputDir.getAbsolutePath() + '\\ic_launcher2.png -w ' + size + ' -h ' + size + ' --export-area-page'
            def process = cmd.execute();
            process.waitFor();
        }
    }
}


// make sure the convertDrawable task is executed somewhere in the make process
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    preBuild.dependsOn(convertDrawable)
}
```

Here are the resources I used:

- [Gradle Doc *Chapter 15: More about Tasks*](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html)
- [Gradle Doc *Chapter 58. Writing Custom Task Classes*](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html)
- [Gradle Doc *Exec function*](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html)
- [Groovy execute()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy)
- [Stackoverflow *Run task before compilation using Android Gradle plugin*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853130/run-task-before-compilation-using-android-gradle-plugin)
- [Groovy Doc for File](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html)