# Executing a shell script as a task using gradlew

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

Here is what I do in general build.gradle without gradlew.

```
task play(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'sh', './test_work.sh'
}

build.dependsOn play
```

This is the first task gets executed when I run gradle build.

I want to do the same thing when I run **gradle assembleDebug**. Here is what I am doing right now:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion A
    buildToolsVersion "X.Y.Z"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "helloWorld"
        minSdkVersion X
        targetSdkVersion Y
    }
    buildTypes {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = file("$project.buildDir/outputs/helloWorld.apk")
        }
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}

    task test(type: Exec) << {
    println "Hi"
    commandLine 'sh', './new_test.sh'
    }
}

repositories {
    ....
    } 

dependencies {
    ....
    }

}

assemble.dependsOn deployGitHooks
```

Somehow the task **test** is not getting executed.

Can anybody please help.

Thanks...

Comment: Why would it execute? No task depends on it. So unless you execute gradle test, it won't execute. Also, you're configuring the task in the  execution phase.

Comment: I added `assemble.dependsOn deployGitHooks` all I want to do is let assembleDebug depend on it.How can I do that ? I mean all I want to execute new_test.sh as the first task, when I run gradle assembleDebug.

Comment: Then name your task `deployGitHooks`. You've named it `test`. And remove the `<<`.

Comment: So, if you try what you mentioned it executes the task and prints "Hi". However it does not execute the script new_test.sh.

Comment: Here is how I got it to work: 
`task deployGitHooks(type: Exec) {
         def script = "bash git_hooks.sh".execute()
         script.in.eachLine {line -> println line}
         }`
[run-task-before-compilation-using-android-gradle-plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853130/run-task-before-compilation-using-android-gradle-plugin)