# Call a command-line tool from a Gradle script

Tags: android, gradle

I have an Android project where some Java source files are auto-generated using a command-line tool.

How can I include this command in my Gradle script so that it is executed when I build my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Gradle's [Exec task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) to specify a program and its arguments.  Then insert the task as a dependency of the task that requires the program to have been run.

Comment: Thanks! How do I specify my task as a dependency for compilation? (the "assemble" task I guess?)

Comment: Well, if you're building java files that need to be available before compilation, you'd want to make that happen before the task that compiles your java.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853130/run-task-before-compilation-using-android-gradle-plugin