# How to run multiple tasks before compilation using Android Gradle plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

I wanted to run tasks by running scripts through Gradle with all the tasks run before compilation to automate generation of artifacts to run the Android app.

Tasks:

1. I want to run a `.cmd` file that generates artifacts
2. Copy the generated artifacts to the Android assets folder

Here's the module build.gradle:

```
task createArtifacts(type:Exec) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "$rootDir\\create-artifacts.cmd"
    workingDir "$rootDir"
}

task copyAssets(type: Copy) {
    from "$rootDir/../Artifacts/assets"
    into "src/main/assets"
}

afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.javaCompiler.dependsOn[copyAssets] //How do I make this multiple in this part?
    }
}
```

So I want to do the task `createArtifacts` before `copyAssets` inside the `afterEvaluate`.

My reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16853376/1968739).

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have default build variants : `debug` and `release`.

This is how I do into my projects:

```
afterEvaluate {
   if (project.hasProperty("assembleRelease")) {
      assembleRelease.dependsOn copyAssets
      copyAssets.dependsOn createArtifacts
   }
   if (project.hasProperty("assembleDebug")) {
      assembleDebug.dependsOn copyAssets
      copyAssets.dependsOn createArtifacts
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to make a successive call of the tasks, making the copyAssets run after createArtifacts.

Comment: This is what the code I've posted is supposed to do. The build depends on "copyAssets" which depends on "createArtifacts". Thus "createArtifacts" is run before "copyAssets".

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating another task called `order` and call that final task inside `afterEvaluate` to ensure the order is followed.

```
task createArtifacts(type:Exec) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "$rootDir\\create-artifacts.cmd"
    workingDir "$rootDir"
}

task copyAssets(type: Copy) {
    from "$rootDir/../Artifacts/assets"
    into "src/main/assets"
}

task order {
    dependsOn 'createArtifacts'
    dependsOn 'copyAssets'
    tasks.findByName('copyAssets').mustRunAfter 'createArtifacts'
}

afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.javaCompiler.dependsOn(order)
    }
}
```

Now, the batch scripts are run before the actual app build is done so my dependencies are always updated everytime I build the app.